# Converting image buffer data to images and saving in local drive node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a very complex program in node.js that reads an image, does some modifications on the image and then converts it into buffered data. The buffered image data looks like this.

> <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 04 38
> 00 00 04 38 08 06 00 00 00 ec 10var fs = require('fs')

To generate this buffered data, I used:

```
fs.readFile('image.jpeg', function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err
    else console.log(data)
}) 6c 8f 00 00 20 00 49 44 41 54 78 5e ec 5d 77 9c 14 45 f6 ... 1001138 more 
    bytes>
```

Is there a way to convert this back to an image and save it in my local drive folders using node.js.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had converted an image to a buffer and then used the `WriteFileSync()` function, from the fs module, to get the image back and save it as a jpeg, this worked perfectly for me.

This idea came from the article: https://medium.com/@divinehycenth8/convert-a-base64-data-into-an-image-in-node-js-d82136576e35

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const image = imagePath/image/imageLocation;

const imageBufferString = image.buffer.toString("base64");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have an image as buffer, you can write the buffer to an image like this (writing only the callback)

```
function callback(err, data) {
 let filename = "test.jpg";
 fs.writeFile(filename, data, "binary", (err) => {
     if (!err) console.log(`${filename} created successfully!`);
   }
}
```